# Expect message on mocked actor when testing with TestKit

Tags: scala, unit-testing, akka

I am trying to test an actor, that depends on another actor. In the following test `ActorA` sends `MessageA` to `ActorB` and expects a `MessageB` in return.

Since this is a Unit test for `ActorB`, I am mocking `ActorA`. My problem now is, that i want to be sure that `ActorA` gets `MessageA`, but when i call the `expectMsg` (see the commented line) the whole autopilot does not seem to work anymore.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
class MyTest(_system: ActorSystem) extends TestKit(_system)
  with WordSpecLike
  with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  object Start
  object MessageA
  object MessageB

  def this() = this(ActorSystem("TestSpec"))

  override def afterAll() {
    system.shutdown()
  }

  // will later be mocked
  class ActorA extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case MessageA => sender() ! MessageB
    }
  }

  class ActorB(actorA: ActorRef) extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case Start => actorA ! MessageA
      case MessageB => println("Got MessageB")
    }
  }

  "" should {
    "work" in {
      val actorA = TestProbe()

      actorA.setAutoPilot(new AutoPilot {
        override def run(sender: ActorRef, msg: Any): AutoPilot = {
          msg match {
            case MessageA => sender ! MessageB
          }
          TestActor.KeepRunning
        }
      })

      // this will break the test
      //actorA.expectMsg(MessageA)

      val actor = system.actorOf(Props(new ActorB(actorA.ref)))
      actor ! Start
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should expect MessageA after sending start to your ActorB.

```
  val actor = system.actorOf(Props(new ActorB(actorA.ref)))
  actor ! Start

  // this will not break the test
  actorA.expectMsg(MessageA)
```